# UI Bootstrap Datepicker for Angular - select all day in a month when clicking on month name

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

Is it somehow possible to make a function in ui.bootstrap.datepicker, that select all days in the shown month when clicking on the month name in the top?

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker

Comment: are you asking if it would select the entire month?

Comment: No, I am asking how I can implement a feature doing that ? :-)

Comment: seems to be not possinle. these are 3rd party libraries, so in backend of library mont name function has already process to go to year. Then you need to fork library in github and u need update library by yourself then install your updated from git

Comment: When I'm looking to do something like this I usually use ngx-daterangepicker-material this allows you to have predefined ranges. such as "This Month", "Today", "This Year"

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion was that it isn't possible to do that using UI Bootstrap with out manually changing the source code